# Why freezing GridView header is not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, scroll

I have the following `GridView` inside a `Panel` which has the `overflow: scroll` to allow scrolling:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="pnlScroll" CssClass="pnlScroll">
    <asp:GridView AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#E2E2E2" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="There is no data to display" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="yourTasksGVHeader" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Task Name" HeaderText="Task Name" SortExpression="TaskName" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="DepartmentName" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="TheStatus" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due Date" SortExpression="DueDate" ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="Link" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Details" SortExpression="TaskDetails" ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

CSS:

```
#yourTasksGV {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#yourTasksGV th {
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    background: url(../theImages/gridHdr.png) repeat-x;
}
#yourTasksGV th a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#yourTasksGV th a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#yourTasksGV td {
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    border-right: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
}
.yourTasksGVHeader {
    position: relative;
    top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
    z-index: 10;
}
.taskTableColumn a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.taskTableColumn a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.pnlScroll {
    height: 750px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow: scroll;

    /* IE */
    scrollbar-base-color: #A0A0A0;
    scrollbar-base-color: #A0A0A0;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #A0A0A0;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #A0A0A0;
    scrollbar-track-color: #EBEBEB;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #A0A0A0;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #A0A0A0;
}
```

When I scroll, the header is supposed to stay intact while the rest of the table scrolls. But that is not happening, as I scroll the header also scroll along and out of view.

How do I modify my code to make it work? (I am testing it on IE8)

Comment: Try removing the top: from .yourTasksGVHeader and adding display: block.

Comment: Nope, the header still scroll with the content :/

Comment: I have something very similar, and just verified that it in fact does not work with IE8 (it's an intranet site, and we're using IE11).

Comment: Damn it... Any alternate solution for IE8?

Comment: I've used some javascript solutions before, though I have never found anything I particularly liked.  http://www.fixedheadertable.com/ is one example.  My biggest gripe is the performance hit on the client side when the table is relatively large.

Comment: Yes that won't work for me but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set GridView `ShowHeader = "false"` and make a separate header for the GridView by using HTML Table and places the GridView just below the Table. So the header row is always fixed there and we can scroll the GridView and see the data.
Insert this before your GridView In html :

```
 <div style="width:478px;border:1px solid #084B8A;color:#ffffff;font-weight:bold;">
        <table bgcolor="#3090C7" rules="all" >
            <tr>
                <td style ="width:71px;">Task Name</td>
                <td style ="width:180px;" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentMain$yourTasksGV','Sort$DepartmentName')">Department</td>
                <td style ="width:90px;">Status</td>
                <td style ="width:60px;">Due Date</td>
                <td style ="width:78px;">---</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I would love to except, I wouldn't be able to do sorting if it is outside of the GridView :/

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Yes , but this solution work in every browsers.

Comment: You could look at the generated links for the default header, and recreate that behavior in the fixed header.  JavaScript might be the easiest way.

Comment: You can still sort. Just put a link buttons in the 'header' table and do the sorting. The top:expression thing does not work from IE10 onwards and not at all in other browsers. I use the pre-render event of one of the gridviews to set the column widths so they line up perfectly.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse Would you show me how to do it with mine if you mind? Thanks.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge What is value of link address when you hover the mouse on column to sort?

Comment: `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentMain$yourTasksGV','Sort$DepartmentName')`

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I updated the code, as you see i add an 'onclick' event for the column.this should be work.